# How to send post request to rails action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to rails so I don't know if that is the best practice. I'm trying to send user input from index view to the index action using ajax then update the view with user input. I'm not trying to save this input in the database.

The @url always return nil.

NOTE: I try to create a custom action with no luck because it requires a template.

Thanks in advance :)

The index action

```
def index
    @url = params[:option]
  end
```

The index view

```
<input type="text" id="exampleFormControlInput1">

<p id="resp-result"><%= @url %></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".button").click(function(event){
             var userinput = document.getElementById("form").value;
             console.log(userinput);
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/responses/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {option: userinput},
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(result){
                  alert("success" + result);

                },
                error:function(result){
                   alert("error" + result);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're making an ajax request, you need to respond with json. Setting the value to `@url` will just make it available to your view, which doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: @vich - 100% agree that simply setting the `@url` value is probably not sufficient. However, I do not think it's 100% accurate to say, "Since you're making an ajax request, you need to respond with json." I do ajax requests all the time that receive html as their response. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @jvillian you're correct, I was just making a generalization based on the question. You certainly don't need to respond with json, but from the sound of the question, it's what OP is likely looking for.

Comment: @vich @jvillian Thanks for the reply. sorry I don't understand you. but I try to change the index action to ``` @url = params[:option].to_json ``` but still, I get null in the index view

Comment: I would recommend reading through the [Rails documentation on ajax](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). In short, you want something like `render json: params[:option]`. There's quite a bit to learn about this topic, but I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuna you will need to output response in json. lets assume that your ajax script can send data to ruby on rails backend properly.

Try this

at ajax 
not this

```
  url:"/responses/",
```

but

```
  url:"/responses.json",
```

you can then get result as per

```
alert("success" + result.myurl);
```

you can **myurl** as part of the json response

Finally try this

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        #@url = params[:option]
        @url='nancy more url'
        format.json do
          render json: {myurl: @url}.to_json
        end
    end
end
```